# How can I know the struct 'URLError' has a member 'code'

Tags: ios, swift

When I use the struct `URLError` I can use it's property `code`, likes below:

```
let error = URLError(.cancelled)
let code = error.code
```

But when I jumped to `URLError` defined in `Xcode` I didn't find it contains a member `code`.And it also no clue indicate that `URLError` has a property `code`.

Therefore I searched the source code [NSError.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/NSError.swift). I found `URLError` conform the protocol `_BridgedStoredNSError` and this protocol has a member `code`. So I can use this member `code` in `URLError`. The code likes below:

```
extension _BridgedStoredNSError {
  public var code: Code {
    return Code(rawValue: unsafeBinaryIntegerFromInt(_nsError.code))!
  }

//other code ...
}
```

My question is how can we know the member `code` if we don't have the source code.

And if there are some similar case like that.

Comment: It says in the documentation that URLError contains error codes for NSError, unfortunately there is no further explanation so we just have to understand that we can use the properties for NSError when working winth URLError

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question. If URLError has a `code` property (and it clearly does), why doesn't the header / documentation show it? I suggest filing a bug report.